# jQuery event submit not firing on user action

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to add a generic form onsubmit event listener to wide web site where i cannot add specific event listener to each and single pages.

The event should fire for all "form" element in the page.

What I've tried so far is:

```
$(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(event) {
        alert("submit");
    });
});
```

Example page dom:

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="afield" />
  <button>
  submit!
  </button>
</form>
```

but the event does not fire, do you know what i'm doing wrong?
I cannot edit the form html code, or create event handler targetting specific forms (e.g. by name/id).

Thank you!

Comment: Seems to work perfectly fine -> **https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/7kp86egf/**

Comment: seems you don't have jQuery library on your page....! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **form is getting submitted** cause you need to `event.preventDefault()` the default browser submit.

First make sure you've wrapped your code in DOM ready and
Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method with event delegation.
Use [Event.preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```
jQuery(function( $ ){ // DOM is now ready and $ alias secured

    $(document).on("submit", "form", function(event) { // Future and existent form Elements
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent browser to default submit
        alert("submit");        // do anything you like
    });

});
```

https://api.jquery.com/ready/
http://api.jquery.com/on/
http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

---

Additionally make sure you've included the jQuery library and your `<script>` tag (preferabily) right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Your form seems to be appearing later, it doesn't exist from the begining.

```
$(function() {
    $("body").on('submit', "form", function(event) {
        alert("submit");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add* a jQuery library before your script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("form").submit(function(event) {
           alert("submit");
        });
    });
</script>
```

<sub>*: seems missing to me. Always have an eye on console for errors.</sub>